# Removing a set amount of bytes after a particular offset

Tags: python, offset

I've already searched through the web and spent a whole week searching on this. Extremely lost right now.

I'm new to programming and currently looking for a way to remove a set amount of bytes after an offset value (It does not mean removing everything after that offset).

Right now I only have this

```
filep = open('filepath', 'r+')
filep.seek(offset in dec)
#command to delete a set amount of bytes from here
filep.save()
filep.close()
```

how can i go about in making this work?

Answer (score 4):

As Veedrac already pointed out, the easiest way is to create a new file with the modified content.
If you don't need the original file anymore, you can [move](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) the new file afterwards.

The following code should help you to create the new file.

```
OFFSET = 3
ENDOFFSET = 4

with open( 'file.txt', 'rb' ) as inputfile, open( 'out.txt', 'wb' ) as outfile:
    outfile.write(inputfile.read( OFFSET - 1 ))
    inputfile.seek(ENDOFFSET)
    outfile.write(inputfile.read())
```

The [with-statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is quit handy if dealing with files.

Comment: I'm not convinced you're seeking correctly. Shouldn't it be more like `inputfile.seek(bytes_to_skip, whence=io.SEEK_CUR)` (and yes, `whence`)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! No wonder I haven't found anything like that. So I'll have to truncate from the start to the offset i want and from the end to the last offset of the byte that I want gone and combine the both of them? Can you use whence with the truncate function?

Comment: The code works perfectly for me! Thank you so much, but I can't give a + to it cause I'm lacking of reputation..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You need to rewrite the file. You can only mutate files if either:

- You don't change their lengths
- You change from the end

So you'd have to overwrite all the way to the end and truncate. I recommend just overwriting the file, especially if you write a new file and then move it atomically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to delete bytes from inside the file.

```
def zapper(filepath, offset, length):
    with open(filepath, 'rb+') as filep:
        filep.seek(offset + length)
        data = filep.read()
        filep.seek(offset)
        filep.write(data)
        filep.truncate()
```